# Extend a generic super class in a sub class

Tags: java, generics

A.java

```
public class A<E> {

   Class cClass;

   public A(Class rClass) {
        this.cClass = rClass;
   }

   public E get() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return (E) this.cClass.newInstance();
   }
}
```

A1.java

```
public class A1 extends A {}
```

I am trying to design a class A as generic and class A1 is a sub class of class A. Object creation should look something like this.

```
A<A1> a1 = new A<>();
```

I want provide a way that no one will create an object like this

```
A<B1> a1 = new A<>();
```

where class B1 is not a subclass of A.

How can i resolve this? Error

```
 error: constructor Operation in class A<E> cannot be applied to given types
```

Comment: You defined a constructor that takes an argument and called it with zero arguments. Where do *you* think the error came from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generalization - constructor cannot be applied to given types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240079/java-generalization-constructor-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Comment: Hey i didn't understand could you explain? @SilvioMayolo

Comment: I understand class A requires a constructor, but how would i go about creating a constructor, that could take itself as an argument? I dont know i am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need such construction, but to make your code work, you should add `class A<E extends A>`, if you want

> provide a way that no one will create an object like this
>   `A<B1> a1 = new A<>();` where class B1 is not a subclass of A.

```
public class A<E extends A> {

    private Class<E> cClass;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(Class<E> rClass) {
        this.cClass = rClass;
    }

    public E get() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return this.cClass.newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        A<A1> a = new A<>(A1.class);

        A1 a1 = a.get();

        //error
        //A<B1> a = new A<>();
    }
}
```

You can remove default constructor `public A() {}`, but then in your A1 class you have to add

```
public A1() {
    super(A1.class);
}
```

**UPDATE:** According to your comment, you want to get a class of a generic type at runtime, and that is **not possible**. Take a looke at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) question

Comment: I get a null pointer exception with your code, it doesn't return the object of class A1.

Comment: Sorry, used wrong constructor. You need `new A<>(A1.class)`. Try now.

Comment: Hey, may be i am taking up the design wrong, i have asked a separate question, would appreciate any help https://stackoverflow.com/q/47726237/8181043